# Virtual phone error : "App has stopped working"

Tags: java, android, simulator

I have the following github project

[GITHUB file Project](https://github.com/adnahm1/MomosGrill.git)

Every time I run the app on a virtual phone through android studio it comes up with "App has stopped working". I have updated android studio.

The errors which keep arising in the logcat are as follow:

```
05.182 4961-4961/app.monmos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: app.monmos, PID: 4961
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.monmos/app.monmos.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at app.monmos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:473)
at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
at app.monmos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I have also updated the gradle version and still nothing is working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
tools:context="app.monmos.Signin">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">


<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/edtphone"
    android:hint ="Phone Number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text ="00000001"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
    app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
    app:met_singleLineEllipsis = "true"
    />



    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
        android:hint ="Password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text ="1234"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:met_baseColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
        app:met_primaryColor="@android:color/white"
        app:met_singleLineEllipsis = "true"
        />
</LinearLayout>

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btsSignActive"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />
```

//Added grade file

```
</RelativeLayout>

    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3' +
        '.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they        belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you upload your xml file of this Activity ?

Comment: Added the activity_signin.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have maven set up in your project's gradle file. Your gradle file should look like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: When I change the grade to the code that you have sent, the error which arises is: 1. The configuration is incorrect, and 2. Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.

Comment: Dude you don't have to copy paste all the code. Please post your gradle file in question and I will edit my answer with correct code.

Comment: Yes, sorry Ill add the grade file to my question now.

Comment: There are two gradle files. One of project and one for app module. Copy and paste my code in project gradle. Then compile your code.

Comment: Done all that and implemented the code. However it is still not working. everything is running fine and the build has been successful but it is still not running on the mobile phone.

Comment: There are no errors within code or file. however the app is still not running on the mobile phone.it comes up with a small pop up box and says (App name has stopped working)

Comment: Can you update your project on GitHub? I will create a pull request and fix your code.

Comment: I have committed the work can you please check it out.

Comment: You have added task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
} twice, please remove once in your gradle.

Comment: Done that. removed duplicate.

Comment: I have figured out that there is some problem with the library you are using. Fbutton.java is giving the error and you can not fix that. Try using some other library for button.

Comment: oh okay. yeah that seems to be the error I am constantly getting with FButton. Okay mate thanks for everything i will look into this library further.

Comment: Always ready to help. Can i have some repo for helping you for this? :)